# Automate initialization and configuration of datapower gateway

Tags: ansible, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

As a part of installation of IBM API Connect, I'm installing IBM DataPower gateway.  I think it's best to have a configuration as code approach to initialize and configure DataPower gateway. So, I can reproduce everything later with ease. I found that there's GatewayScript but I'm not sure whether it can do initialization. What would be the available choices? It would be great if we could use something like Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it depends a bit on the form factor of the DataPower instance. If it is a Docker instance you build it up using Docker Compose, but any other form facto, appliance (hardware), VMware or Linux App, you need to initialize it through either SOMA (Soap management) or RMI (REST Management Interface (=JSON)).

To setup a DataPower as a "copy" the easiest way is to create a backup, and then restore the same, caller a "secure backup". The feature for secure backup must be enabled on the instance when it is first initialized (at first startup) for all but Docker and Linux.

The second option is to use the Export and Import functions. From the Default domain in DataPower you can export all domains.
The disadvantage of that is that you won't be able to get the certificates out so you must re-upload any certificate manually.
(it can be done by script but is a bit arduous).

However, all this is unnecessary if you are running API Connect, as API Connect will setup the DataPower instance for you.
You will just need to point out the DataPower IP and the API Connect does the rest...